# What's the word to describe the procedure that a system enters into normal state?

Tags: single-word-requests

A computer system contains server nodes.

1. At system boots up, a sequence of operations are performed to make the system entering normal running state: a predefined node runs as master and other nodes run as backup.
2. The master node may turn offline. One backup node will be promoted as acting master. This procedure is called `take over`.
3. The offline node goes online again. This procedure is called `recover`.
4. After step 3, the original master node becomes master again and the acting master node abdicate to backup. It's the same sequence of operations as step 1.

I need to name the procedure of step 1 and step 4. What's the suitable word? I know that step 1 is often referred as `initialize`, but it doesn't cover the scenario of step 4.

Comment: *default initialization;* & *reset to default* ? However, a relevant tech Q&A SE site will be more appropriate for this question.

Comment: I don't know what you should call the steps, but in Step 1, "At system boots up" s/b either "As system boots up" or "At system bootup", and "make the system emtering a normal state" s/b "make the system enter a normal state"

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, as a long term systems admin, I would suggest the following (industry standard) terms:

1. `Initialisation`
2. `Failover` (`take over` does not sound right at all)
3. `Recovery`
4. `Reset` (or better `Reinitialisation` if it is indeed the same process as step 1).

I hope that helps.

Comment: Definitely use failover instead of `take over`. (OP, I liked your blog! Sweet post, http://aleung.github.io/blog/2015/01/06/haskell/ )